# My PHP code for retrieving image is ok but no image is shown

Tags: php

This is my getImage.php page for php code

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['email'])){

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        mysqli_select_db($con,"ajmal") or die(mysqli_error($con));

        $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT image FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $imageData = $row["image"];
        }

        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        echo $imageData;
    }
    else{
        echo "Error";
    }
?>
```

and this is my img tag where i use getImage.php page

```
<img src="getImage.php?email = $email" width="100" height="100">
```

and this is the output

[image]

what is the problem with it and what is its solution?

Comment: Where is `$email` set?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked how your HTML is generated at all?

```
<img src="getImage.php?email=<?php echo $email ?>" width="100" height="100">
```

1) in your script, if the e-mail is missing you should set the error code if the response is invalid:

```
else {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo 'E-mail missing';
    exit;
}
```

2) **your script is susceptible** to [SQL injection attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)! Use [MySQLi prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as soon as possible.

Comment: `$email` is a variable containing an email...no problem with the `$email` variable but i don't know where the main problem is... I followed several videos in [http://youtube.com] but every time same arises...